# Check if a system command is finished in R

Tags: r

I run a `system()` command in R, and I am trying to figure out a way to check if my command is finished or is still running.

My command looks like: `system('/usr/bin/java -jar  DatascopeAccess.jar',intern=TRUE,wait=TRUE)`

I tried to add the argument `wait = TRUE`, or to use a while loop or an if condition but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try the `processx` package: https://processx.r-lib.org/#waiting-on-a-process

Comment: what about `any(grepl('java', system('ps', intern = TRUE)))`